# Will copying everything from /data/app and /data/data be enough for app's backup?

Tags: root-access, backup, titanium-backup, xiaomi

I've got an android device (Xiaomi MiPad-I, Stable ROM) which is not quite amenable to rooting, so I can't install Titanium backup on that. However, I can boot the device using the CWM recovery and mount the /system and /data partitions in RW mode during boot time.

In this mode, I can copy anything I want by connecting to a PC and using `adb` commands. However, I want to know whether copying the contents of /data/app and /data/data to my PC be enough for the backup of all apps? Or is there anything else that Titanium backup does? I only need the user apps, system apps are already available by either a factory-reset or flashing a stock ROM.

Comment: You also want to copy everything in `/sdcard/Android`. Some apps store data there and all the OBB files are there, too.

Comment: You also need to backup the symlinks. Only TAR can do that (`adb pull` is not enough, if you wish to simply recover everything with `adb push`, you can't realistically).

Comment: @GiantTree Thanks! What symlinks are needed? Are non-root apps allowed to create symlinks and store data there? I was under the impression that non-root apps are allowed to access only /data/data/package_name and isolated to there only.

Comment: Besides, I only need *data* backup, I can install the apks separately. For example, I need the Firefox cache. I can install Firefox apk anytime, but I need to backup and restore my browsing history.

Comment: *All* apps have a symlink from `/data/data/<package name>/libs` to some directory containing their libraries. They will fail if you simply restore the directory, they need the appropriate symlink to the library folder (because of permissions, ids and some more magic). Reinstalling the app will make sure that symlink is created correctly.

Comment: What if I don't want to backup the Apps (APK) and just their data? As I said in the firefox example, I'm concerned with only the data (browsing history) that firefox has stored. I've got all the APKs backed up separately (ES File Explorer already does it).

So my idea of restore is:
1. Install the APK separately first (firefox_47.apk).
2. Reboot to CWM and copy the /data/data files.

Will that work?

Comment: Yes, but only if you remember to set ownership and permissions correctly. You can get the correct owner from the directory itself and permissions should be 660 for files and 771 for folders (rw-rw---- and rwxrwx--x). Some recoveries come with a "Fix Permissions" function, you may use that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do a backup like you want, you can just copy everything from `/data/data` except the `lib` directories/symlinks (they will fail when you want to restore/push them).

A very easy thing to do is `adb pull /data/data` and then delete all the `lib` files (as symlinks are only files but those refer to directories).

Upon restore you can install each app, using `adb install` for example, and restore the data manually, ie. just push it back and fix permissions.
Make sure the apps in question are **not** running.

To fix permissions you can either do it manually/with a quick shell script. Read the owner of each app's data directory and recursively set that owner (and group) to that owner and group (using `chown user:group -R /data/data/<package name>`). Users and groups are in the format `u0_a000`, the symlink to `lib` is owned by `install`.